# trying to make nr restriction 1-10, but prompt allows users to pick 13

Tags: javascript, if-statement

so i am trying to make a tick system, where i a user can pick a number from 1-10 and there will start a countdown from the number that the user picks to 0. The problem is that when a user picks number 12 in prompt, it doesnt allow him/her to continue, but when they try again it allows them.

html:

```
 <button onclick=start()>Countdown</button>
   <p id="p">
```

scirpt:

```
<script>
var ticks;
var mytimer;

function start() {
    ticks = Number(prompt("where do you want to start a countdown, min 1 max 10")) + 1;
    if (ticks > 11) {
        ticks = Number(prompt("Skriv inn på nytt, tallet må være mellom 3-10")) + 1;
    }
    else if (ticks < 1) {
        ticks = Number(prompt("Try again, The number must be between 1-10")) + 1;
    }
    mytimer = setInterval(tick, 1000)

}

  function tick() {
    ticks--;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Tick nr. " + ticks + "<br />";

    if (ticks === 1) {
        clearInterval(mytimer);
        document.write("Done!");
    }
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untill you are not getting any number between 1 - 10, you may try calling same method again as follow:

```
<script>
var ticks;
var mytimer;

function start() {
    ticks = Number(prompt("where do you want to start a countdown, min 1 max 10")) + 1;
    if (ticks > 10) {
        start();
    }
    else if (ticks < 1) {
        start();
    }
    mytimer = setInterval(tick, 1000)

}

function tick() {
    ticks--;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Tick nr. " + ticks + "<br />";

    if (ticks === 1) {
        clearInterval(mytimer);
        document.write("Done!");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. When you first time enter a value bigger than 11 `if (ticks > 11) {` statement catches it and then shows new prompt. If you again enter a value bigger than 11, there is no if statement to catch it. If you run the `start` function again when a faulty value entered, you can fix this problem.

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense, but do you have any examples on how i can recall the function, is it possible to keep on calling the function in an if statement.

Comment: You can do it like in @Bishal's answer ----> `if (ticks > 11) { start();}`